# Unable to install Allure CLI on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, allure, ubuntu-15.10

According to a [documentation](http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Commandline) it is possible to install **Allure CLI** with `sudo apt-get install allure-commandline` command.

But only Trusty and Precise distributions are supported, hence I can not install it on my Ubuntu 15.10 system.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yandex-qatools/allure-framework
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install allure-commandline
```

Result:

```
E: Unable to locate package allure-commandline
```

Is there another way to install Allure CLI package on Ubuntu 15.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install Allure you need to do the following steps:

- Download the latest version as zip archive from https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/releases/latest.
- Unpack the archive to allure-commandline directory.
- Navigate to bin directory.
- Use allure script to run commandline.

So you can also add unpacked directory to the **PATH** and then use `allure` command as well.

Comment: A special thanks for covering this issue in Allure documentation.

Comment: I followed above steps but still it shows `allure: Command not found`

Comment: The link goes to a deprecated version...
See my comment for an updated link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my script for Ubuntu:

```
# install Java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install default-jre -y
sudo apt install default-jdk -y
javac -version

# install allure
mkdir allure
cd allure
wget https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.13.8/allure-2.13.8.zip

sudo apt install unzip -y
unzip allure-2.13.8.zip
```

And then you can use

```
./allure serve --port 8080 {your_folder_with_xml_results}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the zip file from here:
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip

unzip it:

```
unzip allure-2.7.0.zip
```

and use the executable:

```
allure-2.7.0/bin/allure
```